# Laravel excel: Excel::raw() method not working

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to handle rows with laravel excel, with the 2.1 version I used to use the create method and after that something like this:

```
Excel::create('text', function ($excel) use ($data) { 
     $excel->sheet('Transferencia detalle', function ($sheet) use ($data) { 
           $sheet->row(1, ['DE', 'Para', 'Transferencia #' . $data->id]);}); 
                  })->export('xls');
```

But the method create() was removed in the version 3.1(that I'm using), the thing is in the upgrade guide says that raw() replaces create() https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/upgrade.html, but I get the error `Undefined class constant 'XLSX'` any ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: What version of laravel that you are using?

Comment: @MEDZ "laravel/framework": "5.5.*", should I downgrade the laravel excel version?

Comment: Yes, it's better to do that. Use "2.1", I can confirm that is compatible with Laravel 5.8 as we are using it in our projects.

Comment: @Christian: Please use Excel::download() if you are working in 3.1

Answer (score 1):

The docs aren't very clear on when to include the facade vs the source.  In this case, the constant `XLSX` is in the source, located at `Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel`.  Include this at the top of the file that is making use of the raw function like so:

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel as BaseExcel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
```

Then the code:

```
$raw = Excel::raw(new SomeExport, BaseExcel::XLSX);
```

Should work.

Comment: how to use in thats code in this topic?
$raw = Excel::raw(new SomeExport, BaseExcel::XLSX);

sorry iam newbe